# How to find Geolocation from http server?

Tags: geolocation, google-geolocation

[Geolocation API Removed from Unsecured Origins](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only). Is there any other way to find geoloaction from http server? need some suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IP geolocation service to translate IP address to city location. It has less accuracy compare to Geolocation API. However, it is less intrusive and can be used on all web browsers.

IP Geolocation is available in database or web service format. Below is example for free service.

(a) Database: [IP2Location LITE](https://lite.ip2location.com)

(b) Web Service: [IPInfoDB](http://www.ipinfodb.com)

Reference: https://www.geolocation.com